# Fraction-manipulation between a Gamma and Student-t

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, gamma-distribution, t-distribution

I'm working on a course problem,

> Suppose that $\textbf{x}=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ and $\textbf{y}=\{y_1\dots,y_m\}$ are independent random samples from $\text{N}(x|\mu_x,1/\lambda)$ and $\text{N}(y|\mu_y,1/\lambda)$, respectively. Using the (improper) prior $$\pi(\mu_x,\mu_y,\lambda)=\lambda^{-1},$$ prove that $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are not independent a posteriori and find $\text{Cov}[\mu_x,\mu_y|\textbf{x},\textbf{y}]$.

The given solution begins,

> The likelihood can be written as $$\text{L}(\mu_x,\mu_y,\lambda|\textbf{x},\textbf{y})\propto\lambda^{\frac{n+m}{2}}\exp\left(-\lambda\left(\frac{n}{2}(s_x^2+(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2)+\frac{m}{2}(s_y^2+(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2)\right)\right)$$ thus the joint posterior is $$\pi(\mu_x,\mu_y,\lambda|\textbf{x},\textbf{y})\propto\lambda^{\frac{n+m}{2}-1}\exp\left(-\lambda\left(\frac{n}{2}(s_x^2+(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2)+\frac{m}{2}(s_y^2+(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2)\right)\right)$$ and the marginal for the means is $$\pi(\mu_x,\mu_y|\textbf{x},\textbf{y})\propto\left(1+\frac{1}{ns_x^2+ms_y^2}(n(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2+m(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2)\right)^{-\frac{n+m}{2}}.$$

I see we have \begin{align}\pi(\mu_x,\mu_y,\lambda|\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=\frac{\Gamma(a)}{b^a}\text{Ga}(\lambda|a,b),\text{ with } & a = \frac{n+m}{2}, \\ & b = \frac{n}{2}(s_x^2+(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2)+\frac{m}{2}(s_y^2+(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2),\end{align} but I can't follow the manipulation of fractions in \begin{align}b&=\frac{n}{2}(s_x^2+(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2)+\frac{m}{2}(s_y^2+(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2) \\ &=1+\frac{1}{ns_x^2+ms_y^2}(n(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2)+(m(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2)\end{align} between the last two steps. Would someone mind clarifying?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for fixing the $\mu_x$ for $\mu_y$ typo. The $x_i$ and $y_i$ were accurately quoted, but I don't feel confident in agreeing with the original or with your edit.

Comment: My edit is based on the convention of "$X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F(x)$" (CDF) or "$f(x)$" (pdf), but seldom saw the notation $X_1, \ldots, X_n \sim F(x_i)$, though it is not particularly incorrect.  It's OK for you to revert my edit to follow your original source.

Comment: The support for the prior should be given. Presumably it's on the positive half line for $\lambda$ and on the real line for the other two components, but that's not the only possibility. The two expressions you give for $b$ are not equivalent, but that doesn't of itelf imply an error was made in the original, just in your premises that there's an equality between those expressions.

Comment: @Glen_b "The two expressions you give for $b$ are not equivalent" is useful. Is the difference somehow made up by the final proportionality? I thought the interior of the brackets being 'bound up' by the index $-\frac{n+m}{2}$ would prevent that.

Comment: Consider where the "$1\ +\ $" must come from: a   _constant_   $(ns_x^2+ms_y^2)/2$ has been factored out of the argument of $\exp.$

Comment: @whuber Parentheses fixed in the final quoted expression, I think. I think this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks. The comment is enough for me, but if you care to make it an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the marginal, you need to integrate out the $\lambda$ term in

$$\lambda^{\frac{n+m}{2}-1}\exp\left(-\lambda\left(\frac{n}{2}(s_x^2+(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2)+\frac{m}{2}(s_y^2+(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2)\right)\right).$$

To do this, let's simplify it by replacing that constant positive multiple of $\lambda$ by a single name, such as $z,$ and compute (since evidently $\lambda\gt 0$)

> $$\int_0^\infty \lambda^{\frac{n+m}{2}-1}\exp\left(-\lambda z\right)\,\mathrm dz = z^{-\frac{n+m}{2}}\int_0^\infty (\lambda z)^{\frac{n+m}{2}}\exp\left(-\lambda z\right)\frac{\mathrm d(\lambda z)}{\lambda z} = \frac{z^{-\frac{n+m}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+m}{2}\right)}.$$

(This calculation shows up so often in statistics and mathematics that it's worth remembering.)

We need to identify the portion of this result that depends on $(\mu_x,\mu_y),$ *but any multiplicative factors not involving these variables can be ignored.*

Begin by ignoring the $1/\Gamma((n+m)/2)$ factor and focus on $z$ itself before raising it to the $-(n+m)/2$ power:

$$\begin{aligned}
z &= \frac{n}{2}(s_x^2+(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2)+\frac{m}{2}(s_y^2+(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2) \\
&= \frac{n}{2}s_x^2 + \frac{m}{n}s_y^2 + \frac{n}{2}(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2 + \frac{m}{2}(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2 \\
&= \left(\frac{n}{2}s_x^2 + \frac{m}{n}s_y^2\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{ns_x^2+ms_y^2}(n(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2+m(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2)\right).
\end{aligned}$$

This expresses $z$ in the form $z = (C)\,(f(\mu_x,\mu_y)).$ Its $-(n+m)/2$ power therefore has a constant factor of $C^{-(m+n)/2},$ *which can be ignored.*  Thus

$$z^{-\frac{n+m}{2}}\ \propto\ f(\mu_x,\mu_y)^{-(n+m)/2} = \left(1+\frac{1}{ns_x^2+ms_y^2}(n(\bar{x}-\mu_x)^2+m(\bar{y}-\mu_y)^2)\right)^{-(n+m)/2},$$

*QED.*

The motivation for this last move is, of course, to steer the expression towards something that looks like a Student-t density.

Comment: @mjc It's worth working through this approach on your own; many similar manipulations are going to crop up again and again in a Bayesian context (and indeed, to an extent outside of Bayesian contexts).